# Problem Due to GridView RowDeleting Event in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, gridview, user-controls

I have One GridView in which I added one LinkButton in the TemplateField and Specified its Text as "Delete" and its purpose is to delete the Row.
I have written all the Coding part to delete the Row in the GridView RowCommand Event.
I clicked the GridView RowDeleting Event but I didn't write any code in that event and finally I removed that event both in the .cs file and also in the SourceCode.

But still when I delete the row, one error throws such as

```
 "The GridView 'gvToStock' fired event RowDeleting which wasn't handled."
```

and deleting function is not working.

But At the same time, If I included the RowDeleting Event in the .cs and source code file, its working fine.

What would be the reason for that?

Comment: Do you have a button named 'delete', or with a CommandName set to Delete? This is a reserved name, making the grid-view trigger the event - which you're not handling. That's why it works when you add a dummy event handler.

Comment: I added one Linkbutton in the GridView's TemplateField and its ID is "lnkDelete" and its Text="Delete"

Comment: try to change the ID, just to exclude this as a source of error.

Comment: @MartinHN: Which One I want to change? ID of the LinkButton Or the ID of the GridView.

Comment: ID of the LinkButton. Just to try, I'm not sure it works.

Comment: @MartinHN: Still it throws the same error.

Comment: Ok, you don't have any CommandName specified on the LinkButton?

Comment: @MartinHN: Yes. I have specified the CommandName.

Comment: That's why then. The command name fires the RowDeleting event, but you're not handling it - which is what the error message tells you.

Comment: @MartinHN: Thank you Martin. Ya. Now I understand the reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. As **MartinHN** Said, The Command Name specified in the LinkButton caused the Problem.
The following link describes some detailed explanation about this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx